# Is it possible to stop moving file performed by function QDir::rename in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, rename, qdir

I have created new thread, that performs moving file from one directory to other with function

```
bool QDir::rename(const QString & oldName, const QString & newName)
```

Is it possible to interrupt this moving ?

Comment: I assume you are implying that moving the file may take a long time and you'd like to interrupt this moving if the user pressed "Cancel" (for example).

Comment: Not an answer, but the QDir docs mention nothing about interrupting, cancelling, stopping, monitoring, or progress. So I'd guess that via this interface that is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy directory using Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536524/copy-directory-using-qt)